# Apache 2.4 get request processing time in microseconds log

Tags: apache-httpd, logs

Trying to add the %D and %T format string to my Apache log to see time for request processing but apparently not able to. Here are the `LogFormat` directives in my `httpd.conf`

```
[root@server01 admin_ad2]# grep LogFormat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
[root@server01 admin_ad2]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)
Server built:   May 28 2018 16:19:32
```

Adding the format string a shown below and restarting the Apache service does not have any affect - still can't see the value in my `/var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log`

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" **%T/%D**" combined
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: On RHEL, the httpd SSL configuration should be defined in a separate .conf file that also specifies log settings. Can you take a look inside the conf.d directory?

Comment: @Haxiel Makes sense. So the LogFormat directive is not inherited from the main configuration file ? How would I declare it in ssl.conf?  can't see any LogFormat directive in there ....

Comment: The RPM I have shows a [TransferLog directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#transferlog) for ssl_access_log. The linked page shows an example on how to define LogFormat for that directive.

Comment: Thank you indeed it seams to work :) Please create an answer so that I can accept it for you :)! BTW do you know how would I convert the value in microseconds **18/18695953** to seconds ?

Comment: I've added my answer :-). I didn't quite understand your question about converting the time value. Can you please clarify that with a little more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RHEL version of Apache HTTP server defines the SSL configuration in a separate configuration file, which is located at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`.

This configuration file also defines the log file for the SSL virtual host using the [TransferLog](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#transferlog) directive:

```
# Use separate log files for the SSL virtual host; note that LogLevel
# is not inherited from httpd.conf.
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn
```

The TransferLog directive uses the log format defined by the most recent [LogFormat](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) directive, which does not have a nickname. As a result, the format can be controlled by defining it just prior to the TransferLog directive:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" **%T/%D**"
TransferLog /var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log
```